# Force minimum paper size in "standalone" (or use an alternative)

Tags: standalone, bounding-box

I compile small latex math snippets using the `standalone` document class. I rasterize the resulting PDF to a PNG image using ImageMagick and finally include these images in some HTML document. However, for technical reasons of this procedure, I want to ensure a specific height of the document **above + below the baseline**, let's say the letter "Q" should always fit vertically, even if the document only contains one single "a".

I thought about including a **phantom** letter, but this also introduces additional whitespace in the horizontal dimension. Is there an easy way to tell `standalone` (or a special environment) to at least include a specific height above + below the  baseline of the text? Is there some phantom-similar thing which enlarges the bounding box but doesn't occupy space by itself? I also thought abut a tikz image which doesn't draw anything but specify a bounding box. However, including the tikz package for this reason only will make compilation very slow since I have to compile dozens of latex snippets.

I use `lualatex` (but only because of the easy integration of true type fonts) and currently I compile the latex snippets using the following document template (the `...` is replaced with the latex snipped to be rendered):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$...$
\end{document}
```

(If this is not possible, I'll just use a phantom text to specify my minimum vertical bounding box + auto-crop the rasterized image horizontally.)

Comment: There is `\vphantom` that only uses the vertical dimensions.

Comment: Nice! This solves the problem. Thank you, @egreg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to do it; the simplest is perhaps to use `\vphantom{Q}` instead of `\phantom{Q}`, that uses only the vertical dimensions of "Q".

Another method is to use a strut:

```
\begin{document}
\strut a
\end{document}
```

The command `\strut` produces an invisible object such that its height and depth sum up to the baseline skip. Here are three examples: the first is with

```
\begin{document}
Q
\end{document}
```

the second with

```
\begin{document}
\vphantom{Q}a
\end{document}
```

and the third is with the strut. I've added the frames to better see the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the second solution, which is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: I'm still struggling: I want exactly `2\baselineskip` above and below the baseline of the text (so I can exactly measure where the baseline is in the rasterized image plus measure the line spacing). The "Q" only was a start to solve the problem. Like with the "Q", the strut will not allow me to measure the baseline exactly. Can you please help me again? I hope you understand the problem. ;) Thanks!

Comment: @leemes Try `\vrule width 0pt height 2\baselineskip depth 2\baselineskip` in place of `\strut`

Comment: Ok this was fast. And it works like a charm, like expected ;) Thank you so much!