# How to force a minimum width for a snippet in "standalone"

Tags: width, textwidth

My question is very similar to [this one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84548/force-minimum-paper-size-in-standalone-or-use-an-alternative) However, my request is for a minimum width, instead of a minimum height. 
I need to create little snippets of formulas with LaTeX. I'm using TexMaker to write out the formulas and then export whatever I have to PNG-s. 
What I need is a way to specify a minimum width for the final snippet. So, if the length of my formulas exceeds that minimum, the width is set at their length. However, if said length doesn't exceed the minimum, the width of the PNG is set at the minimum.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Varwidth supplies a maximum width, but the width can be less (no mimium),  Varwidth works great with `$\displaystyle ...$` but with amsmath (equation, align, etc.) not so much.

Comment: Can you give feedback on the provided answers?

Answer (score 2):

A rough proposal, `30mm` is the minimum width parameter and `A` is the desired content of the document. Change `0pt` to `0.3pt` to see the "invisible placeholder".

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
A\\[-\baselineskip]
\rule{30mm}{0pt}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
% or \documentclass[varwidth, margin=0.3pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$a^2+b^2 = c^2$\\[-\baselineskip]
\rule{30mm}{0pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This tests the width of varwidth, but uses a minipage if it is less than the minimum specified.

```
\documentclass[multi=snippet,class=article]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\snippetbox}

\NewEnviron{snippet}[1]{% #1 = minimum width
  \savebox{\snippetbox}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\BODY\end{varwidth}}%
  \ifdim\wd\snippetbox<#1\relax
    \begin{minipage}{#1}\BODY\end{minipage}%
  \else
    \unhbox\snippetbox
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{snippet}{1in}
  $\displaystyle x=a$
\end{snippet}

\begin{snippet}{1in}% push limits
  $\displaystyle x=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h$
\end{snippet}


\begin{snippet}{1in}
  \begin{equation} z=c \notag \end{equation}
\end{snippet}

\end{document}
```